# Cloned github repository url lead to error in google colab

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm working on a google colab available at this link: https://colab.research.google.com/github/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings/blob/main/Lyrics%20inspired%20AI%20paintings.ipynb

On github: https://github.com/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings

I would like to store all the files regarding my project on my own github repository, so I cloned a few public repositories for example:

https://github.com/openai/CLIP

https://github.com/kostarion/guided-diffusion

The following script works fine,

```
import pathlib, shutil, os, sys
useCPU = False #@param {type:"boolean"}

if not is_colab:
    # If running locally, there's a good chance your env will need this in order to not crash upon np.matmul() or similar operations.
    os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='TRUE'

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
USE_ADABINS = True

if is_colab:
    if not google_drive:
        root_path = f'/content'
        model_path = '/content/models' 
else:
    root_path = os.getcwd()
    model_path = f'{root_path}/models'

multipip_res = subprocess.run(['pip', 'install', 'lpips', 'datetime', 'timm', 'ftfy', 'einops', 'pytorch-lightning', 'omegaconf'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
print(multipip_res)

if is_colab:
    subprocess.run(['apt', 'install', 'imagemagick'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')

try:
    from CLIP import clip
except:
    if not os.path.exists("CLIP"):
        gitclone("https://github.com/openai/CLIP")
    sys.path.append(f'{PROJECT_DIR}/CLIP')

try:
    from guided_diffusion.script_util import create_model_and_diffusion
except:
    if not os.path.exists("guided-diffusion"):
        gitclone("https://github.com/kostarion/guided-diffusion")
    sys.path.append(f'{PROJECT_DIR}/guided-diffusion')

**... other modules and packages in the same structure**

import torch
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import partial
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import gc
import io
import math
import timm
from IPython import display
import lpips
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import requests
from glob import glob
import json
from types import SimpleNamespace
from torch import nn
from torch.nn import functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as T
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from CLIP import clip
from resize_right import resize
from guided_diffusion.script_util import create_model_and_diffusion, model_and_diffusion_defaults
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from ipywidgets import Output
import hashlib
from functools import partial
if is_colab:
    os.chdir('/content')
    from google.colab import files
else:
    os.chdir(f'{PROJECT_DIR}')
from IPython.display import Image as ipyimg
from numpy import asarray
from einops import rearrange, repeat
import torch, torchvision
import time
from omegaconf import OmegaConf
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)
```

but when I change the links

https://github.com/openai/CLIP --> https://github.com/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings/tree/main/CLIP

https://github.com/kostarion/guided-diffusion --> https://github.com/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings/tree/main/guided-diffusion

got the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-b4c7e2b3bdd9> in <module>()
    107 import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
    108 from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
--> 109 from CLIP import clip
    110 from resize_right import resize
    111 from guided_diffusion.script_util import create_model_and_diffusion, model_and_diffusion_defaults

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CLIP'
```

What is wrong with my approach? I'm new on this field, so sorry if this is some basic thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Github repository should be referred to as follows

```
https://github.com/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings
```

But this contains folders for the cloned repositories so the `path` needs to include the folder as follows.

```
sys.path.append(f'{PROJECT_DIR}/lyricstopaintings/CLIP')
```

I couldn't get `from CLIP import clip` working so I changed it to `import clip`.

I cut down the code to be a minimal example because I couldn't find some of the functions such as `subprocess.run` and `gitclone` so I replaced these with other functions.

```
import pathlib, shutil, os, sys
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())

!pip install -q ftfy

try:
    import clip
except:
    if not os.path.exists("CLIP"):
        !git clone -q "https://github.com/lyricstopaintings/lyricstopaintings"
        sys.path.append(f'{PROJECT_DIR}/lyricstopaintings/CLIP')

import clip
clip.available_models()

#
['RN50',
 'RN101',
 'RN50x4',
 'RN50x16',
 'RN50x64',
 'ViT-B/32',
 'ViT-B/16',
 'ViT-L/14',
 'ViT-L/14@336px']
```